# Intersect GET or POST request with SailsJS

Tags: sails.js

I know about the Lifecycle callbacks, but I would like to write a helper class that would intersect the response from the controller and have access to the model attributes.

Is there a way I can do this for all my controllers or is there perhaps a library that enables something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what your asking for is post processing, the best sails has to offer at this time (because it does lack afterFind() lifecycle request) is to edit a custom response.

http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/Custom-Responses

Comment: That is exactly what I mean, thank you. This will work rather well for me.